# How to use image inside javascript component with Vaadin 7

Tags: javascript, java, image, google-maps, vaadin

I use Vaadin 7 framework for my project.

I have to display a map (like google map) which is controled by a javascript api (like openlayers or others).

I understood that I had to use a component that extends the AbstractJavaScriptComponent to be able to publish the requisite javascript file to control and create the map using the @JavaScript annotation.

It works well : when I launch the App, my Map is well initialized (initialized with my javascript codes provided with the component) and well displayed too.

However, for a good user interface, I would like to display on the Map some image icons for some POI (Point Of Interest) features. So in the javascript code which controls the Map, I have to reference the image path. 
But regardless where I put the image file in my Vaadin project, it is not reachable from the javascript code when my application is deployed.

How can I "publish" some image files from the server for its to be reachable by the javascript code (client side) ?

I tried to add the image file in the @Javascript annotation but it did not work.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I solved the issue easily. the VAADIN folder is automatically exposed from the server et can be accessed by the client. So I put my images in the VAADIN folder and in the javascript client side I was able to access the images with the path /VAADIN/image_file_name.png

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the [GoogleMaps Add-on](https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/googlemaps-add-on) which has brilliantly wrapped a lot of the google maps JS API functions.